# POST request is not returning the same status code as browser

Tags: python-requests, http-post

I am using Python library requests to call a POST API but it is not returning the expected status code as it should and doing in the browser.
Things I have made sure or already tried.

- Copied all the headers from the browser request, even request made in incognito mode has the same headers
- Checked redirect history and found it empty
- Tried "allowRedirect"= False, then checked redirect history

Basically what is happening in the browsers is, that if the API is called with the correct credentials then the response code is 302 and the new API is called. But if the credentials are wrong then API responds with some gibberish HTML with 200 as response code. And no matter what I do I am unable to get 302 as response code from the Python script.

Comment: It is possible that the server is configured to redirect on success, but not on failure. In this case, you will need to check the content of the response to see if it contains the expected redirect URL

Comment: Yes @c0d3x27 , that's the case, the server is configured to redirect on success. But I am saying I am unable to recreate the case of success using script. In case of success, the response code is 302 otherwise 200 but no matter what I tried from the script I never got 302 as a response code.